# Не меняется свойство Visibility Grid'a в UWP приложении

Tags: c#, uwp

На нажатие по кнопке в программе Grid из Collapsed должен стать Visible.
 Класс:

```
public class Building : MainPage
        {
            public List<Grid> pathsIs { get; private set; }
            public Building()
            {
                pathsIs = new List<Grid>();
                initPath();
            }
            public void checkPath(int indexOf = -1)
            {
                if (indexOf == -1)
                {
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    pathsIs[indexOf].Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }
            }
            private void initPath()
            {
                pathsIs.Add(robotoLabPath);
                pathsIs.Add(lep1_2Path);
                pathsIs.Add(lep3Path);
                pathsIs.Add(lep4Path);
                pathsIs.Add(lep8Path);
                pathsIs.Add(ep4Path);
                pathsIs.Add(lec1_2Path);
                pathsIs.Add(lec3Path);
                pathsIs.Add(lec4Path);
            }
```

Сам метод:

```
private void robotoLab_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Building b = new Building();
    b.checkPath(0);
}
```

Само свойство меняется в методе класса, но при возвращении в метод кнопки меняется обратно на Collapsed.

Так же GIF поясняющий что происходит в VS: https://gyazo.com/5b6efe03ab181dac2710de213aee4507

Comment: Есть хороший шанс, что `robotoLabPath` в одном и другом случае разные. Не могли бы вы на `robotoLabPath` сделать правый клик и Make Object ID?

Comment: @VladD проверил, это именно тот. Он меняется внутри класса, после выхода сразу возвращается в исходное положение.

Comment: Точно тот? Хм, **очень** странно, ведь вы в методе `robotoLab_Tapped` создаёте **новый** экземпляр `Building`, который снаружи никому не виден и теряется после окончания работы метода `robotoLab_Tapped`. Окей, тогда попробуйте подписаться на изменения (знаете как?), и посмотрите, кто меняет значение назад.

Comment: @VladD а ест вариант создать `Building` сразу на всё, допустим как глобальная переменная в C++? Если есть, то как? К тому же, нигде в классе `Building` не уточняется что `robotoLapPath` должен быть `Collapsed`, а в свою очередь это делается при загрузке страницы лишь один раз(не путать с методом `MainPage()`). Очень странно для меня наблюдать что элемент UI меняет значение сам по себе. Не знаю если честно как подписаться на изменения.

Comment: @VladD вот ссылка на `Object ID`. https://gyazo.com/8b44a86fbe67717e391e713db3656948

Comment: Подписаться на изменения так: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8482969/276994 (при этом возможны утечки памяти, но это ж только для отладки).

Comment: С object id у вас что-то не то. Надо вот как: http://i.stack.imgur.com/5mjpU.png, http://i.stack.imgur.com/HooAv.png

Comment: @VladD ладно, как я понял, действительно создаются новые экземпляры, получается мне нужно действовать через `static`, а для этого придётся потратить много времени и изменить код. Я нашёл другой способ, но всё равно спасибо за потраченное время!